# Get the name of currently executed macro in Excel VBA

Tags: vba

How to get the currently executed macro name in Excel VBA?

```
Sub WhateverMacroName()
    MsgBox (GetTheNameOfCurrentlyExecutedMacro)
End Sub
```

Which should return `WhateverMacroName`

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/InsertProcedureNames.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That which is not exposed must be remembered.

Define a Global variable and have each Sub setup the variable at entry.  Thus a general error handler can determine a miscreant.

If you have a nested call structure *(with subs calling subs)*, you will need to implement a stack.

Comment: In other words, you say, there is no such thing like ActiveMacro analogically to ActiveSheet or ActiveCell? Or may bee you say that you do not know if such a thing exists?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin read e.g. [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/accessing-the-call-stack-in-an-excel-vba-macro.4015153/).